# Get two tables with different row length in one line

Tags: tables, pdftex, minipage, tabularx

Code:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{.55\textwidth}
{\tiny{table1}\newline\newline}
\input{"/path/to/table1.txt"}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
{\tiny{table2}\newline\newline}
\input{"/path/to/table2.txt"}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}
```

table1.txt:

```
{\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.45\textwidth}|rr}
  \hline
 & B1 & B2 \\ 
  \hline
  A1 & 80 & 12 \\ 
  A2 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  B & 1 & 5 \\ 
  C & 3 & 1 \\ 
  C & 3 & 1 \\ 
  C & 3 & 1 \\ 
  C & 3 & 1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
```

table2.txt:

```
{\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.45\textwidth}|rr}
  \hline
 & A1 & A2 \\ 
  \hline
  A & 1 & 2 \\ 
  B & 1 & 5 \\ 
  C & 2 & 5 \\ 
  D & 3 & 8 \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
```

Question:

The two tables are not in the same level. The row length of table2 is smaller than the row length of table1. Therefore table2 to is setted centered towards table1.

How to get them in one line if the row lengths of table1 and table2 are not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always make your code runnable (`R` for example is not a defined column type by default) but you probably want `\begin{minipage}[t]{...}`  and `\begin{tabularx}{<width>}[t]{...}` in both cases so they align at their tops.

Although simpler would be to have `[t]` on the `tabularx` but not have the minipage and flushleft environments at all as they are not doing anything very useful, you can have two tables on the same line without wrapping them in minipage.

Comment: EDITED: R converted to -> r

Comment: @b4154 your example does not make sense after the edit as `tabularx` has to have a column based on the `X` column type,  presumably `R` was such a defined column. with just `p` and `r` `tabularx` can not work at all. This is why examples should always be _complete_ documents so that you can test them before posting.

Comment: @ David Carliste: \begin{tabularx}[t] does not work. \begin{minipage}[t] solves the problem. But if I have no caption, e.g.: {\tiny{table1}\newline\newline}, using \begin{minipage}[t] does not work to get the tables in one line

Comment: @Mico thanks (hard to remember your own syntax:-)

Comment: Carliste - I used {tabularx}[t] instead of {tabularx}{\\textwidth}[t]. Therefore the error. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the `[t]` positioning specifier to the two `minipage` declarations, you should use `\caption` commands and remove some unused code. For the `tabularx` environments, use `X` instead of `p{0.45\textwidth}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip} % whitespace below caption
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\scriptsize % Don't use "\tiny" unless you have contempt for your readers
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.55\textwidth}
  \caption{table1}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|rr@{}}
  \hline
  & B1 & B2 \\
  \hline
  A1 & 80 & 12 \\
  A2 & 1 & 2 \\
  B & 1 & 5 \\
  C & 3 & 1 \\
  C & 3 & 1 \\
  C & 3 & 1 \\
  C & 3 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill} % Maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
  \caption{table2}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|rr@{}}
  \hline
  & B1 & B2 \\
  \hline
  A1 & 80 & 12 \\
  A2 & 1 & 2 \\
  B & 1 & 5 \\
  C & 3 & 1 \\
  C & 3 & 1 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why to use {\linewidth} after {tabularx} and not e.g. {1.0.\textwidth}?

Comment: @b4154 - In this case, `\linewidth`, `1.0\linewidth`, `\textwidth`, and `1.0\textwidth` all work equally well. In contrast, `1.0.\textwidth` won't work because of the stray `.` ("period", "full stop").

Comment: @b4154 - Out of curiosity: Why did you go ahead and "accept" the other answer? Should I delete my answer as it is apparently of no use to you?

Comment: No, do not delete please. But I did not understand your answer 100% and therefore I asked you about \linewidth